# Retrieve query_string on my CGI in ksh/html

Tags: bash, cgi, query-string, ksh

I've this ksh script in my CGI :

```
SERV_LINUX=$(cat /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)

DATE_Linux=$(cat /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt | awk -F';' '{print $3}' | sort | uniq)

echo "<form action="LINUX_GNU.ksh" method="post">"
echo "<select name="SERV">"
echo "$SERV_LINUX" | while read SERV_LINUX; do
echo " <option value="$SERV_LINUX">$SERV_LINUX</option>"
done
echo "</select>"

echo "<select name="DATE_Linux">"
echo "$DATE_Linux" | while read DATE_Linux; do
echo " <option value="$DATE_Linux">$DATE_Linux</option>"
done
echo "</select>"

echo "<input type="submit" value="Select">"
echo "</form>"

echo "</div>"
```

This piece of script create a dropdown menu which allow to choose a server. On my second page, If I put this :

```
read a 
echo $a
```

I'm able to retrieve the query string like this :

```
SERV=my_serv&DATE_Linux=2019-10
```

I want to know if it's possible to do the same things but only with button ? I mean, If I've 4 options in my dropdown menu, I would like to create 4 buttons, like that :

```
SERV_LINUX=$(cat /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/foo.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)

echo "<form action="test.ksh" method="post">"
echo "$SERV_LINUX" | while read SERV_LINUX; do
echo "<input type="submit" value="$SERV_LINUX">"
done
echo "</select>"
echo "</form>"
```

But When I try that, I've no result... Do you think it's possible ? Do u have any idea to do this ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing escape sequences everywhere. You need to correct that. This worked for me :

```
SERV_LINUX=$(echo -e "server1\nserver2\nserver3" | sort | uniq)

echo "<form action=\"test.ksh\" method=\"post\">"
while read SERV_LINUX; do
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"$SERV_LINUX\">"
done <<< "$SERV_LINUX"
echo "</select></form>"
```

Let me know if it helps.